# Can you redefine an @mixin inside of an @media query?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have the following @mixin defined in my SCSS to create font-sizes in both pixels and rems:

```
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1){
font-size: ($sizeValue * 10) + px;
font-size: $sizeValue + rem;
}
```

I then have the following:

```
h1 { @include font-size(1.6) }

h2 { @include font-size(1.4) }

h3 { @include font-size(1.2) }
```

but when the screen is under 480px, I would like to reduce the font size by 80% but so far the following code isn't working:

```
@media(max-width:480px){ 
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1){
font-size: (($sizeValue * 10) * 0.8) + px;
font-size: ($sizeValue * 0.8) + rem;
}}
```

Is it possible to redefine a @mixin inside of a @media query? What would be the best way to go about doing this? I want to do this without having to include the h1, h2, h3 rules again.

Comment: If you're using rem, why not just change the `font-size` on the body for the different media queries. Users with browsers that only support px will survive if the font is slightly larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional argument to your mixin:

```
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1, $ratio: 1){
  font-size: (($sizeValue * 10) * $ratio) + px;
  font-size: ($sizeValue * $ratio) + rem;
}
```

Then, save your header values as variables:

```
$header-1: 1.6;
$header-2: 1.4;
$header-3: 1.2;
```

Finally:

```
h1 {
  @include font-size($header-1);
}

@media(max-width:480px) {
  h1 {
    @include font-size($header-1, .8);
  }
}
```

Which will generate:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12.8px;
    font-size: 1.28rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this isn't working.

The rule doesn't get compiled into CSS, at least for me.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer and also changed it based on your edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks your answer does work, but my intention was to find a way without having to redefine all my headers again within @media.

Comment: I thought there would be a way to just pass the ratio value into the existing @mixin just once, since the font sizes remain the same.

Comment: A mixin is just a block of text that can be `@included` and thus repeated (like copy and pasted) in multiple places, if you redfine a mixin in the `@media`, it doesn't 'know' about any of the other times you included it.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to redefine all your headers, the solution is to change the mixin to include the media query

```
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1){
    font-size: ($sizeValue * 10) + px;
    font-size: $sizeValue + rem;

    @media(max-width:480px) {
        font-size: (($sizeValue * 10) * 0.8) + px;
        font-size: ($sizeValue * 0.8) + rem;
   }
}
```

But keep in mind that the css output will be like this with the @media rule repeated for each header

```
h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 12.8px;
        font-size: 1.28rem; 
    }
}
h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    h2 {
        font-size: 11.2px;
        font-size: 1.12rem;
    }
}
h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem; 
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    h3 {
        font-size: 9.6px;
        font-size: 0.96rem;
    }
}
```